# Linear Algebra Friedberg Exercise 1.7.7 Query

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I will now state the exercise:

"Prove the following statement. Let β
be a basis for a vector space V, and let S be a linearly independent
subset of V. There exists a subset S1 of β such that S ∪ S1 is a basis
for V."

My question regards a fact he uses in his solution which I cannot understand how he deduces. I will now describe his solution and explain which part confuses me:

He starts by considering the family $F$ of all linearly independent subsets of β such that their union with S is linearly independent. Then he proves by the maximal principle (as referenced in his book page 59) that $F$ has a maximal element, denoted S1.

He then goes on to state precicely that **"By the maximality of $S_1$ we know that $S_1 \cup S$ generates $β$ "**

I understand why that implies our desired result, but what I don't understand is why it is true.

How do we know that  $S_1 \cup S$ generates $β$ ?

Thank you in advance, any help is very much appreciated

Comment: for a direct proof see https://math.solverer.com/library/stephen_friedberg/linear_algebra/exercise_1-7-7?utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So assume for contradiction that $S_1\cup S$ does not generate $\beta$. Then in particular, there is some $v\in\beta$ not generated by $S_1\cup S$. You can then check that this implies by definition that $S_1\cup S\cup\{v\}$ is also independent. Thus $S_1$ is not maximal as it is bounded above by $S_1\subsetneq S_1\cup\{v\}\subseteq \beta$.

Comment: Thank you very much, gonna have to keep that in mind when choosing families of functions for similar exercises, +1